# DOS FOR loop pass a counter

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I am attempting to use a DOS for loop to copy a file and add an integer of the loop counter to the file name.  The first file Fred.bat has the loop code..

```
for %%i in (1,3,1) DO Barney.bat
```

This batch file when executed calls the Barney batch file three times (successfully)

The called batch file Barney.bat has the file copy command...

Copy fred.txt wilma%%1.txt

And successfully copies the fred.txt to the wilma%1.txt.  However I was attempting to get the loop counter %i from the FOR loop passed to %i variable in second batch file so I ended up with three files (wilma1.txt, wilma2.txt and wilma3.txt).

Is there a way to pass the loop counter variable to the second batch file using the DOS FOR command so I can get the desired result.

Comment: Are you *really* using DOS? Or are you speaking about the command line in Windows?

Comment: Don't sure I fully understand the issue, but can't you simply pass the `%i`as a parameter to the second batch file ? So ending with `[...] `DO Barney.bat %i` ? (and getting this parameter with `%1`)

Answer (score 2):

Fred.bat :

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,3) DO Barney.bat %%i
```

**Edit :**

Barney.bat

```
Copy fred.txt wilma%1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for you prompt replies.  Yes I do mean command line in Windows (it was once known as DOS when I first learned played in the late 80s).  SachaDee thank you for you very helpful reply - it almost seems to work.  However, when I run you suggestions the output files are wilma%1.txt, wilma%2.txt and wilma%3.txt (rather than without the % character in the file name).  I've attempted a few permutations of using % or %% but can't seem to get the desired result of wilma1.txt, wilma2.txt and wilma3.txt. Would appreciate any additional suggestions

Comment: Sorry I Thinked that you need the `%`. Check my edit !